# Passenger raises error: `initialize': No such file or directory

Tags: nginx, passenger, raspberry-pi, redmine, raspbian

I'm trying to run redmine with passenger. I ran the fowllowing command:

```
sudo passenger start RAILS_ENV=production
```

and get the following exception:

```
Stopping web server.../var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/daemon_controller-1.1.5/lib/daemon_controller/lock_file.rb:63:in `initialize': No such file or directory - /usr/share/nginx/www/redmine-install/RAILS_ENV=production/passenger.3000.pid.lock (Errno::ENOENT)
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/daemon_controller-1.1.5/lib/daemon_controller/lock_file.rb:63:in `open'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/daemon_controller-1.1.5/lib/daemon_controller/lock_file.rb:63:in `exclusive_lock'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/daemon_controller-1.1.5/lib/daemon_controller.rb:289:in `stop'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-4.0.18/lib/phusion_passenger/standalone/start_command.rb:637:in `block in stop_nginx'
    from <internal:prelude>:10:in `synchronize'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-4.0.18/lib/phusion_passenger/standalone/start_command.rb:634:in `stop_nginx'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-4.0.18/lib/phusion_passenger/standalone/start_command.rb:104:in `rescue in run'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-4.0.18/lib/phusion_passenger/standalone/start_command.rb:114:in `run'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-4.0.18/lib/phusion_passenger/standalone/main.rb:92:in `run_command'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-4.0.18/lib/phusion_passenger/standalone/main.rb:62:in `run!'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-4.0.18/lib/phusion_passenger/standalone/main.rb:39:in `run!'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-4.0.18/bin/passenger:36:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/bin/passenger:23:in `load'
    from /usr/local/bin/passenger:23:in `<main>'
```

I've installed passenger with nginx the following way(on a raspberry pi with raspbian):

```
Recompile nginx with passenger support as the standard ubuntu version doesn't have it.

sudo gem install passenger --no-ri --no-rdoc
sudo passenger-install-nginx-module
sudo passenger

Choose /usr/local/nginx as installation directory.

Change the following line in /etc/init.d/nginx:
#DAEMON=/usr/sbin/nginx
DAEMON=/usr/local/nginx/sbin/nginx

In /etc/nginx/nginx.conf add the following to the http section:

passenger_root /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-4.0.18;
passenger_ruby /usr/bin/ruby1.9.1;
```

I'm not sure how to fix this error. Some help would be grateful!

Answer (score 1):

You invoked `passenger start` wrong. As you can see in `passenger start --help`, it accepts an optional argument `[directory]`, which points to the application directory. You are essentially telling it that the application directory is located in `RAILS_ENV=production`, which obviously isn't a valid directory.

The proper way to set RAILS_ENV is through the `--environment` option. See `--help`.